# How do I wait to see if my InputStream has received all data to process further?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, inputstream, outputstream

I have to write data to `Amazon S3` and I write data using `OutputStream` to its `InputStream` as follows

```
    final PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
    final PipedInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new PipedInputStream(outputStream);
        new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(S3EnvironmentConfigurator.BucketTypes.source.name(), getProposalName(uniqueId), inputStream, null);
                        amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
                        try {
                            inputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }
        ).start();
```

Now `amazonS3Client.putObject` looks like

```
  @Override
    public PutObjectResult putObject(@Nonnull final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest)
            throws AmazonClientException, AmazonServiceException {

        try {
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(putObjectRequest.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            String read = br.readLine();
            while(read != null) {
                System.out.println(read);
                read =br.readLine();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //ignore
        }
    return super.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

- This currently prints out the content on console

**Needed**

How can I do something like

```
while (putObjectRequest.getInputStream() is not completely available) {
   // wait
}

// write inputStream, the entire InputStream is ready and available for processing
```

Comment: Why do you need to wait? Why can't your start processing without waiting? If data isn't ready yet current thread just pauses until input stream has new data.

Comment: Why the pipes? There's no advantage in this situation. Just do all the I/O in the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

Once the side writing closes its `OutputStream`, the `InputStream` will deliver any bytes that have not yet been read, and then the next [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) after that will return -1 to indicate end of input.

> The value byte is returned as an `int` in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

If the side writing fails to [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close%28%29) when its done, then the reader will block waiting for more input until the writing process closes.

Comment: Does that mean that the inputStream holds all the data once `outputSteam.close() ` is called?

Comment: @daydreamer, Unless the stream library is horribly buggy, the writer can safely call `close` and the reader will still be able to process all the bytes written.

Comment: @daydreamer, One place where bugs tend to creep in is when you buffer.  If you wrap an `OutputStream` in a buffering output stream, then you need to close/flush the buffered output stream, not just the stream that it wraps.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy all data to byte buffer and thus be sure that you've read all data from input stream. And then create new input stream based on this buffer. Something like:

```
byte[] array = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
InputStream newInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
```

[IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from apache commons.